# Prevent MassTransit from creating a RabbitMQ exchange for a consumer host

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

Is it possible to configure MassTransit to not create a RabbitMQ exchange for a consumer host? My RabbitMQ user has not enough rights to declare an exchange at the host where the consuming queue is located, so MassTransit fails to start with the following error:

`Unhandled Exception: MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqConnectionException:
Operation interrupted ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedExcept
ion: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, c
ode=403, text="ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange '***' i
n vhost '***' refused for user '***'", classId=
40, methodId=10, cause=`

Here is the code that I use:

`var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
{
    var host = sbc.Host(host: "***", port: 5671, virtualHost: "***", configure: configurator =>
    {
        configurator.UseSsl(sslConfigurator =>
        {
            sslConfigurator.Certificate = certificate;
            sslConfigurator.UseCertificateAsAuthenticationIdentity = true;
            sslConfigurator.ServerName = "***";
        });
    });
    sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "***", endpointConfigurator =>
    {
        endpointConfigurator.Consumer<UpdateCustomerConsumer>();
    });
});`

Comment: How do you expect it to work if there's no exchange to bind to?

Comment: MassTransit must be able to declare exchanges and queues, so allow those permissions on your connection or it will not work.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev The consumer is supposed to read from an existing queue, the exchange and bindings to the queue should be created by the producer (an external service).

Comment: Well, you are using the default configuration, which configures everything automatically. If you want to consume from a pre-configured exchange, you need to use an explicit binding http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/topology/rabbitmq/binding.html

Comment: But if your credentials won't even allow to create the binding, it would be hard to achieve anyway.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I understand, thank you for your help. I will check if I can get appropriate permissions.