# MassTransit ACCESS_REFUSED on exchange not specified in the code

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, access-denied, masstransit

I'm using a very basic example for testing my MassTransit connection to rabbitMq through C#. Whenever I run this code to connect to my rabbitMq endpoint, it works fine whenever I have a wildcard set as permission. However, when I add the permissions in the rabbitMq admin to only allow this user to access the `test` event, this code will fail.

For some reason it will first try to connect to an exchange name that I guess is generated (by MassTransit?):

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: 'The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=403, text="ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange '*ComputerName*_dotnet_bus_73451gfsgerqwrefxfddgf' in vhost '/' refused for user 'user'", classId=40, methodId=10, cause='
```

So the exchange `*ComputerName*_dotnet_bus_73451gfsgerqwrefxfddgf`, after that it will try to connect to the `test` exchange. Of course I can add the `ComputerName....` exchange to the permissions but then this would need to be done for each computer trying to run this code. Why is MassTransit trying to connect to this exchange? Is the code incorrect or is this just how MassTransit works?

This is the code for the test application (I altered this a bit so it might not run right of the bat, but, in general the code runs fine):

```
using System;
using MassTransit;

namespace Test
{
    public class Testing
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Consumer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
            {
                var host = sbc.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://servername"), h =>
                {
                    h.Username("user");
                    h.Password("user");
                });

                sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "test", ep =>
                {
                    ep.Handler<Testing>(context =>
                    {
                        return Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received: {context.Message.Id}");
                    });
                });
            });

            bus.Start();

            // For testing purposes, we send a message ourselves.
            bus.Publish(new Testing { Id = "X" });

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for messages. Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

            bus.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Image of the rabbitMq admin user permission:

[image: Regex rabbitmqadmin permissions]

Answer (score 1):

> Is the code incorrect or is this just how MassTransit works?

More than likely this is just how MassTransit works. See this other question: [Prevent MassTransit from creating a RabbitMQ exchange for a consumer host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55282409/1466825)

Strangely enough I could not find this information anywhere in the MassTransit docs.

You'll have to grant the `configure` permission for exchanges containing the string `dotnet_bus`. More than likely other permissions like `read` and `write` will be required.

Comment: There are other exchanges and/or queues that might be created as errors and such come up in a running production system. Trying to lock down MassTransit can lead to the inability to recover from failures if MT can't create error queues, etc. There are also Fault exchanges and other things that may be created when bad things happen. If they can't be created, MT will be stuck unable to continue.

Comment: The odd thing is, i'm just trying to connect to the 'test' exchange, why would masstransit create two exchanges? one for test and one generated with the dotnet_bus in it?

Comment: MassTransit does a lot of things "for you", for better or worse. This must be one of them. I suggest asking support forums specific to that library.